# Java setMethod dose not work. When I pass the value to the setMethod it doesn't pass it to line

Tags: java

I have a Result class in which I keep all values/results.
All my code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        Result result = new Result();
        Divider divider = new Divider();
        String[] myTestArray = new String[]{"1234", "12"};
        if (myTestArray.length != 2) {
            System.out.printf("You can not use %d arguments. " +
                    "To perform division, you need to use 2 arguments `", myTestArray.length);`
            System.exit(1);
        }
        int dividend = Integer.parseInt(myTestArray[0]);
        int divisor = Integer.parseInt(myTestArray[1]);
        divider.divide(dividend, divisor);
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
        formatter.format(result);
    }
}
    
public class Divider {
    Result result;

    public Divider() {
        this.result = new Result();
    }

    /**
     * divide method performs division of two numbers
     */
    public void divide(int dividend, int divisor) {
        result.setDividend(Math.abs(dividend));
        result.setDivisor(Math.abs(divisor));
        result.setQuotient(divideTwoNumbers(result.getDividend(),
                result.getDivisor()));
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public int calculateProduct(int partialDividend) {
        int multiplicand = divideTwoNumbers(partialDividend, `result.getDivisor());`
        result.setProduct(multipleTwoNumbers(result.getDivisor(), `multiplicand));`
        result.setRemainder(partialDividend - result.getProduct());
        return result.getProduct();
    }

    /**
     * Method divideTwoNumbers is used instead of operands "/"
     */
    public int divideTwoNumbers(int dividend, int divisor) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; dividend >= divisor; i++) {
            dividend = dividend - divisor;
            result++;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Method multipleTwoNumbers is used instead of operands "*"
     */
    public int multipleTwoNumbers(int multiplicand, int multiplier) {
        int product = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < multiplicand; i++) {
            product = product + multiplier;
        }
        return product;
    }
}
```

I think, my problem is around here somewhere

```
public class Formatter {
    Result result;
    Divider divider;
    private int firstIndexPartialDividend = 0; // find the beginning of the number
    private int countSpace = 0; // space counter

    public Formatter() {
        this.result = new Result();
        this.divider = new Divider();

    }

    public void format() {
        // print the first row
        printFirstRow();
        String dividendText = Integer.toString(result.getDividend());
        for (int i = 1; i <= dividendText.length(); i++) {
            result.setFirstPartialDividend(Integer.parseInt
                    (dividendText.substring(firstIndexPartialDividend, i)));
            // print the second row
            if (result.getFirstPartialDividend() >= result.getDivisor() &&
                    firstIndexPartialDividend == 0) {
                countSpace = dividendText.length() - i;
                printSecondRow(result.getFirstPartialDividend());
                firstIndexPartialDividend = i;
                // To align the space in the next row.
                if (Integer.toString(result.getProduct()).length()
                        > Integer.toString(result.getRemainder()).length() &&
                        result.getRemainder() > 0) {
                    countSpace = Integer.toString(result.getProduct()).length()
                            - Integer.toString(result.getRemainder()).length();
                } else {
                    countSpace = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * printFirstRow method - print the first row of an application
     */
    public void printFirstRow() {
        System.out.printf("%d|%d\n", result.getDividend(), `enter code here`result.getDivisor());
    }

    /**
     * printSecondRow method - print the second row of an application
     */
    public void printSecondRow(int firstPartialDividend) {
        divider.calculateProduct(firstPartialDividend);
        System.out.println(result.getProduct() + getSpace(countSpace) + `enter code here`"|" + (result.getQuotient()));
    }

    /**
     * getSpace method to get the number of spaces you want
     */
    public String getSpace(int count) {
        String space = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            space += " ";
        return space;
    }
}

public class Result {
    private int quotient; // keep the result of division
    private int dividend;
    private int divisor;
    private int firstPartialDividend; //keep the result of division the `enter code here`first partial dividend
    private int product;
    private int remainder;

    `enter code here`public Result() {
        this.dividend = dividend;
        this.divisor = divisor;
    }

    public int getQuotient() {
        return quotient;
    }

    public void setQuotient(int quotient) {
        this.quotient = quotient;
    }

    public int getDividend() {
        return dividend;
    }

    public void setDividend(int dividend) {
        this.dividend = dividend;
    }

    public int getDivisor() {
        return divisor;
    }

    public void setDivisor(int divisor) {
        this.divisor = divisor;
    }

    public int getFirstPartialDividend() {
        return firstPartialDividend;
    }

    public void setFirstPartialDividend(int firstPartialDividend) {
        this.firstPartialDividend = firstPartialDividend;
    }

    public int getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(int product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public int getRemainder() {
        return remainder;
    }

    public void setRemainder(int remainder) {
        this.remainder = remainder;
    }
}
```

[image]

values are still 0

My program should print long division result

Like this:

```
1234|12
12  |102
  34
  24
  10
```

Of course this is not the whole program, I am still working on it.

Comment: Seems like a good opportunity to learn to use the debugger properly. Can you reduce your code to a [mcve]?

Comment: Does this given code actually compile? You have no method `Formatter.format(result)` defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image shown has stopped before the assignment is complete. The parameter value is 1234, and the current value of `this.dividend` is zero. If you step the debugger forward, both will have the value of `1234`

---

Your setters are working fine. You are just not calling the setters on the correct instances.

Regarding the "issue". You have a `Result` and `Divider` instance in main method that is not given to the `Formatter`. When you create a `new Formatter()` it has its own instances that are initialized with the default values of zero.

You probably should have a constructors that carry through the same instances. For example

```
Result result = new Result(); // this probably isn't even needed
Divider divider = new Divider(result);  // param could be removed
divider.divide(x1, x2); // This method could create and store `new Result()` value on its own
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(divider, result); // again, result not needed since it would be internal to the divider
formatter.format();
```

(and your formatter should probably only "format the result" as the name implies instead of also doing calculations with the Divider instance)

You can also remove `new Main()` since that isn't doing anything

Answer (score 0):

OneCricketeer - thanks a lot!!!
I has changed constructor Divider and Formatter.

```
    Result result = new Result();
    Divider divider = new Divider(result);
    divider.divide(dividend, divisor);
    Formatter formatter = new Formatter(result);
    formatter.format();
```

- 

```
   public Divider(Result result) {
    this.result = result;
}
```

- 

```
  public Formatter(Result result) {
    this.result = result;
    this.divider = new Divider(result);

}
```

Now my output is

```
1234|12
12  |102
```